# protecting against injection in an advanced MySQL stored procedure statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, sql-injection

I am using an `XML` string passed into a stored procedure to store data into my database.

In general, I use `PDO` to create prepared statements to avoid `SQL injection` via `bindParam()` and `bindValue()`, then `execute()`. However, in order to optimize my database, I have decided to implement a stored procedure that takes in a large set of `XML` data and does all of the writing at once.

The stored procedure will use an iterator to go through the XML and insert rows into the database.

Using `ExtractValue` which uses [XPath](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/) notation, I can do something like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`$DBU`@`%` PROCEDURE `write_comment_rows`(In xml_string text) 
BEGIN
    insert into my_table (comment) values (
        ExtractValue(xml_string, 'user_data/comment_field') 
    );
END;
```

How can I make sure the data in my `XML` stored in `comment_field` is safe to put into my database?

Comment: In scenarios like this, always make sure to escape the data that is inserted before you output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no optimization in this approach. A PHP-based parsing, followed by a series of prepared inserts wrapped in a transaction, would be blazing fast.

Anyway, there are [inline prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) can be used in a procedure

Comment: So it would be strictly better to simply begin a PDO transaction, prepare a large SQL query with many inserts, then execute it, and commit?

Comment: No. Prepared statements do not work this way. Rather begin a PDO transaction, prepare a small SQL query with single insert, then execute it for all the rows, then commit.

Comment: Thank you. This improved my query speed by 15% in my benchmark analysis.